# How do i call a dictionary value from user input

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new to programming, this is also my first post.

The problem is;

Ask the user how their weight is from a 1 to 4 scale.

```
1 = 0.5, 2 = 1.2, 3 = 1.7, 4 = 2.4.
```

I set up my dictionary like this.

So when the user inputs `2`

When I execute print, it prints `2` and not `1.2`. 
how do I update the new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need

```
 scal3 = {"1":0.5, "2":1.2, "3":1.7, "4":2.4}

 n = input("enter a number: ")

 print(scal3[n])
```

or if you don't want it to throw error if user enters wrong key

```
print(scal3.get(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the keys in your dictionary in string type, you will have to convert the user input `(string)` to integer.

Also, for printing the desired output you need to access the dictionary for value with a key. You can do that simply by : `my_dict[key]` . This will give you the value for key.

Try this :

```
weight_dict = {1 : 0.5, 2 : 1.2, 3 : 1.7, 4 : 2.4}

input = input("enter a weight: ")

input_weight = int(input.strip())

print("Weight on scale is : {0}".format(weight_dict[input_weight]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, Daniel!

If I understand correctly, you have 1, 2, 3, and 4 as keys corresponding to 0.5, 1.2, 1.7, and 2.4, respectively.

Since input is accepted as a string, we must convert it to integer, like so:

```
weights_dictionary = {1: 0.5, 2: 1.2, 3: 1.7, 4: 2.4}

user_weight = int(input("Enter weight from 1 to 4:"))

print(weights_dictionary[user_weight])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you should do:

```
weight = int(input("Enter your Weight: "))

def getScale(weight):
    return {
        1 : 0.5,
        2 : 1.2,
        3 : 1.7,
        4 : 2.4
    }.get(weight, 0.5)


print(getScale(weight))
```

Using the second parameter of `get(weight, 0.5)`, you can define what happens when value entered by user is not in the `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is printing the value of the input instead of value of the 
key in the dict. In dict there is a mapping between key and value.
So if you want to print the value of the key 2 you need to ask the dict for the value of key 2.That is done by calling the dict with that particular key .So if we suppose you made a dict called weights like this 
`

```
weights ={1:0.5,2:1.2,3:1.7,4:2.4}
```

then to get the value for key 2, we need to call the weights with the following syntax.

```
value = weights[2]
```

Please check this code and run it to have a better understanding of the problem.

```
weights ={1:0.5,2:1.2,3:1.7,4:2.4}
user_input = 0 
while user_input not in (weights.keys()):
    user_input = input("Please input the value for weight between 1 to 4: ")
print("Value of weight = %s"%weights[user_input])
```